# Can bug reports and feature requests requiring SE Dev attention be reported on per-site metas, or do they need to all go here?

Tags: support, per-site-meta, bug-reports, feature-request-process

A member of one of the sites I participate in is experiencing a bug exclusively on that site. Since being concrete is generally helpful, [this is the bug](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5037/1204).

There is some concern over whether bugs get noticed on per-site metas, so I figured I'd ask to clarify: if we post a bug or a feature request on a per-site meta, do the Stack Exchange devs notice it, just like if it were posted on Meta Stack Exchange? Or do bugs and feature requests requiring their attention exclusively need to go here?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Really this is a duplicate, although old posts might be somewhat confusing to new users because of the switch from meta.stackoverflow.com to meta.stackexchange.com so I think this is worth answering again.

For bugs that affect **only** a particular site (for example, a CSS bug in one of the themed sites, or a bug that is data-dependent), please ask on the meta for that site.  So: a bug that only affects bicycles.stackexchange.com should be posted on bicycles.meta.stackexchange.com.

There are also many bugs that affect all sites.  Those bugs should be reported on meta.stackexchange.com.

**However**, the above is just our guidance on the right audience to report to; we have ways to search across the entire network, so bugs posted on any meta will be noticed.

Comment: Problem with per site meta is we can't really bump questions and it feels like it's a "lost case". For example [this bug](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/2636/links-in-promotion-ads-are-black-on-black-thus-invisible) I reported is resulting in ugly design and it feels like it's going to take 6-8 years to fix. Here in MSE I could put a bounty to give it more attention, and in there don't want to do trivial edits.

Comment: @ShadowWizard the thing that is most likely to get more attention for a bug report, assuming it's reasonable and fixable, is upvotes.  You *might* catch the eye of one of the community managers by using a bounty, but it's pretty rare (afaict) that someone other than a dev escalates a bug (I've seen Joel do it).

Comment: Well, it's the [second highest scored bug report already](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/bug?sort=votes&pageSize=15).

Comment: That's kind of a one-off example, because visibility isn't the issue there (a dev reported it, after all - and I've seen him bring it up internally as well).  I'm not sure I can speak to why that one hasn't been addressed, but visibility isn't it.

Comment: @ShadowWizard My vague hope is that SE decided to significantly change the Skeptics design at some point, which would make fixing these small bugs a waste of time. There are quite a few more similar bugs on Skeptics, link visibility is broken in several places. (I've no inside information here, it's just a wild guess that is likely to be wrong).

Comment: Thanks @MadScientist this indeed makes sense and explains the secrecy around it.

Comment: When I said "I'm not sure I can say", I meant that I don't know why there hasn't been any response to the skeptics theme requests.  I wasn't trying to be cagey.

Answer (score 8):

> I'd expect the default forum would be a question on the site's own meta

That's correct. First, bring it up on the site specific meta - the community (and moderators) should all be involved in deciding whether a feature should or should not be enabled (and possibly what form it should have).

> but I don't know if the moderators there would necessarily have the power to effect a requested change if they wanted to

Some things moderators can do, others they can't, but can escalate to Stack Exchange employees - the community managers.

Additionally, the community managers do monitor feature requests on all meta sites, so they will see such requests and act on them (assuming the community comes to a consensus).

> would such a request need to be raised on meta.SE to be seen by someone capable of considering and delivering that change?

As I outlined above, no - such a *site specific* request should be raised on the site specific meta.

Answer (score 2):

There is (to my knowledge) no standard process, but from what I know, the correct place to ask about site-specific **anything** is the site meta.

Only [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)s and [bug](/questions/tagged/bug)s affecting the *complete* SE-Network <s>should be</s> are often better off on MSE, because of the larger audience, which is often very involved in already existing requests and reports.

To my knowledge employees regularly patrol site-specific metas looking for new bugs and feature-requests (which are probably added to the issue-tracker subsequently). Additionally every mod can contact the team **directly**. But there's a **lot** of open bugs and a **lot** of open feature-requests, so don't be discouraged when it takes some time ;)

Comment: Even bugs and feature requests that effect the whole network are fine to be asked on site-specific metas - Stack Exchange employees monitor all the meta sites for these.