# How to switch to meta.stackexchange from other SE sites

Tags: support, hyperlinks, meta, usability

The context of this question is that I have been thinking of reporting a bug I found on other SE site, so I need access to this meta.SE site.

When I try using the site switcher on the top left of the page, I cannot find a link to switch to SE. What I need to do is:

- either manually type `meta.stackexchange.com` in the browser URL bar, or
- do the trick of going to any SE site, then going to the tab "Edit Profile & Settings` and click "Network Profile" on top right.

Is there a more simple and more usable way of switching to SE / meta.SE from other sites in the Stack Exchange network?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In the drop-down, there should be an *edit* link next to YOUR COMMUNITIES.

In there, you can add a site to be included in the list and/or move sites around from the default sort.

Comment: Yes, I guess this is the correct answer. Thank-you.

Comment: @AI E, Maybe the people in SO could implement an easier link, or a trick less hard trick to figure out?

Comment: Possibly. The default sort is by reputation points, descending, so except for those few people are active in a lot of sites it's more than sufficient. It seems plenty discoverable to me; I didn't know how to do it until I opened the menu and spotted the edit link, then tried it out.

Comment: There's also a search box just below the list on the same menu, which would probably only need a couple of characters to be typed.

Answer (score 6):

There's a link in the footer of each site that includes Meta.StackExchange.

> [image]

Comment: It it hard to figure out. Thank-you

Comment: Well, to be fair nobody reads the footers of webpages.

Comment: @JonW Reading footers of webpages was how I first became an SE member (passively browsing Maths SE reading their content, saw in the footer that there's a Sci-Fi & Fantasy SE, joined and started posting there, the rest is history).

Answer (score 5):

The "Stack Exchange" menu button in the top bar is actually a link to https://stackexchange.com/.

> [image: Screenshot]

Normally, clicking that button just opens the site switcher menu.  But on Firefox (at least), if you **middle-click the button**, it will act like a normal link, and open https://stackexchange.com/ in a new browser tab.  (Of course, right-clicking and using the context menu will work, too.)  From there, you can get to meta.SE using the same site switcher menu in the normal way.

Of course, this is kind of a [hidden feature](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8211/hidden-features-of-stack-exchange), but it can be handy if you know about it.  Alas, it turns out that it's also browser-dependent; on Chrome, middle-clicking just opens the menu. :(

---

**Ps.** If you want to go directly to meta.SE, you can find it in the site switcher menu itself by typing "meta" into the search box:

> [image: Screenshot]

[As Al E. notes](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/272473), you can also add it into the customizable "Your Communities" section of the menu (by clicking the *edit* link), so that it's always just one click (well, two clicks — you need one to open the menu in the first place) away.

---

Also, you don't *need* to go to meta.SE to report bugs; the SE dev team [does track bug reports on per-site metas.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/240568/can-bug-reports-and-feature-requests-requiring-se-dev-attention-be-reported-on-p)  If the bug seems to only appear on a specific site, it's usually best to report it on that site's meta; for bugs that affect multiple sites on the SE network, meta.SE is indeed the right place.  Either way, though, as long as you use the [bug](/questions/tagged/bug) (or [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request)) tag, the devs will notice it.

Comment: No, doesn't work with Chrome. Middle clicking also opens the drop down same as left click. Probably some forgotten feature of the SOUP.

Comment: @ShadowWizard: No, it's not SOUP-related; I did check that before posting. But you're right, it seems to behave differently on Chrome than on Firefox. Not sure why.

Comment: Yeah, weird. [Related Super User post](http://superuser.com/questions/501561/middle-mouse-click-doesnt-always-open-links-in-a-new-tab-in-chrome).